# For the Mystic's Psionic Investigation feature, how often can the intangible psionic sensor be activated?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, unearthed-arcana, mystic

In the [UA Mystic class](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf), if you select Order of the Awakened it comes with a 3rd level ability called [Psionic Investigation](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf#page=6) that can read "the psionic imprint left on an object" to review events in its recent past. It also comes with the following extra feature:

> Additionally, you can embed an intangible psionic sensor within the object. For the next 24 hours, you can use an action to learn the object’s location relative to you (its distance and direction) and to look at the object’s surroundings from its point of view as if you were there. This perception lasts until the start of your next turn.
>
> Once you use this feature, you can’t use it again until you finish a short or long rest.

Does this mean you can only activate that intangible psionic sensor once during the next 24 hours, once per short/long rest during the next 24 hours, or that you can only embed a new sensor once per short/long rest?

For instance, if my mystic put a sensor onto a queen's crown at midday, can I see through the crown as often as I like (taking one action to do so each time and gaining one round of vision), even dozens of times, before midday tomorrow, or only once before midday tomorrow?

I guess I'm asking does "this feature" in the final sentence refer to the first sentence or the second sentence of the quoted paragraph?

Comment: Good question, and it might be worth sending Crawford a tweet on that one, given that it is UA and UA has tended to have a lot of ambiguities in them ...

Comment: I agree, since I know how I would answer this one, but it would be totally subjective since it can be interpetated three ways as BlackPudding's question shows us quite clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is not official, [a March 2017 tweet by Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/841461165167333376) suggests that the once per long rest applies to the feature as a whole, rather than being able to "visit" the sensor multiple times:

> *Psionic Investigation, intangible psionic sensor: can only be used 1/long rest. Applies to spying on the sensor too?*
>
> **Doesn't apply to the sensor. It applies to the feature as a whole.**

So by specifically stating that the 1/long rest limit doesn't apply to the sensor, it implies that the sensor can be visited multiple times during the 24 hour period.